# Show that $ f \circ g $ is self-adjoint iff $ f \circ g = g \circ f $ in a euclidean vector space.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

This question has been asked before [HERE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2889184/f-circ-g-self-adjoint-iff-f-circ-g-g-circ-f?rq=1), but I could not understand the following result from the linked post:

> $$ \langle F(G(v)), w \rangle
> = \langle G(v), F(w) \rangle
> = \langle v, G(F(w)) \rangle $$

The rest of the proof of the "$\Rightarrow$" direction is clear to me, but I am also not so sure how to approach the "$\Leftarrow$" part of the proof, that is: $ f \circ g = g \circ f \Rightarrow f \circ g = (f \circ g)^*$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first part, the adjoint of a linear operator $T$ is defined to be the unique operator $T^*$ such that:
$$\langle Tv,w\rangle=\langle v,T^*w\rangle,\ \forall v,w\in V$$
Now, since $F,G$ are assumed to be selfadjoint, that is $F=F^*$ and $G=G^*$, we get:
$$\langle F(G(v)),w\rangle=\langle G(v),F^*(w)\rangle=\langle v,G^*(F^*(w))\rangle=\langle v,G(F(w))\rangle$$

For the other direction, we have in general that $(T\circ S)^*=S^*\circ T^*$, so:
$$F\circ G=F^*\circ G^*=(G\circ F)^*=(F\circ G)^*$$

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your answer, but the statement only assumes $f \circ g$ to be self-adjoint, can we from this already conclude that  $ f $ and $ g $ are self-adjoint? EDIT: I have to take this back, since we are actually assuming both to be self adjoint and not only the composite... I should have read more carefully!

Comment: Case closed then! Glad I could help!

Comment: Yes, I think I'd still be an interesting question that I am not able to answer, but as far as this exercise is concerned, I am done.

Comment: Well, it has an easy answer: consider any $T\neq 0$ such that $T^2=0$ (e.g. an upper triangular $2\times 2$ matrix with zero diagonal and a non-zero element in the upper right corner). Then of course $T\circ T=T^2=0$ is selfadjoint, but $T$ itself is not.